# Calculating mean of the sliced group after applying sort

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a huge dataframe (downloaded from the hive) and what I am trying to do here is calculate the mean of grouped values after slicing off the first two values and the last value from the sorted group. The following line of code will self-explain what I am trying to achieve:

```
df['col5'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])['col4'].transform(lambda x: x.sort_values()[2:-1].mean())
```

So, I want to obtain the mean of col4 values after grouping the `df` by the first 3 columns (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`). The grouped values of `col4` need to be sorted first, and the first two values plus the last value need to be ignored.

The above line of code throws this error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 47127 elements, new values have 47146 elements
```

I don't understand how the number of elements is coming out to be more than the actual number of rows. What could possibly be the issue?

Another finding is that if I download the table manually from Hive, it gives me the first 10,000 rows. Using the above code on this table yields no error and it works just as it should. However, if I obtain the dataframe using Pyspark, it pulls out the complete data (47146 rows). And, applying the calculation on this dataframe gives out the error.

Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 98, in test_8_validate_days_btw_stats
    .transform(lambda x: x.sort_values()[2:-1].mean())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 955, in transform
    result.index = self._selected_obj.index
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5080, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "pandas/_libs/properties.pyx", line 69, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 380, in _set_axis
    self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 155, in set_axis
    'values have {new} elements'.format(old=old_len, new=new_len))
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 47127 elements, new values have 47146 elements
```

Comment: For a group where `col4` is `[4, 6, 8, 10, 12]`, using `[2:-1]` remove `4, 6, 12`. Is it what you want?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using transform?  Apply should yield want you want without the repeated rows.

Comment: I'm confused by the error. Transform _always_ generates a like-indexed series. It cannot produce an incompatible index. That's the entire purpose of the function. You're calculating the mean of a subset. That should produce a single value, transform should expand that appropriately. `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0] * 5 + [1] * 5, 'B': [10, 11, 17, 13, 15, 2, 3, 19, 20, 21]})` and `df['C'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: x.sort_values()[2:].mean())` works fine. (note you want just `2:` to remove the first 2 elements from the Series)

Comment: Will you expand the ValueError text to include _full_ traceback, and/or extend your code block to include an example which reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: @HenryEcker sorry, my bad! Actually, the last element in the group also needs to be struck off. I just made the edit. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @HenryEcker I added the full traceback in the edit.

Comment: Ah python.2.7 what is the pandas version?

Comment: The issue was that `col3`, which is a part of the groupby operation has only 47127 non-null values. And, that is why it is throwing the length mismatch error. Thanks everybody for looking into it.